# PHP: variable undefined in included or required file

Tags: php, variables, undefined, include-path

Hi I have a problem with a variable not being set. It works normally if I am using a RELATIVE path however when using an ABSOLUTE path php says it is not set.

```
<?php
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('SITE_ROOT', 'G:' . DS . 'htdocs' . DS . 'www');
define('LAYOUT_PATH', SITE_ROOT . DS . 'layout');
require('function.php');    

$user = new User();
$user->set_username('johndoe');

require_layout_template('header.php');
?>
```

Inside my `header.php`:

```
<?php
//if ( isset($user) ) {
    echo $user->get_username();
//}
?>
```

The result of above is this error:
`Notice: Undefined variable: user in G:\htdocs\www\layout\header.php`

However if I use a relative path everything is ok.

I am running at localhost in windows environment and running in PHP Version 5.3.5.

### Update:

It's my fault that I didn't included the `require_layout_template`. I have this function contained in `function.php` to take care of the necessary details for the require.

```
<?php
    //function.php
    function require_layout_template($template) {
        global $user; // added this to solve the problem.
        require(LAYOUT_PATH . DS . $template);
    }
?>
```

I have added the necessary global variable for the variable `$user`.

Thank you @strkol for the idea.

Comment: the variables scope doesn't depend on whether the file is included with absolute nor relative path, so your problem is somewhere else

Comment: in your header.php try to do a echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; What say?

Comment: can you add this line inside header.php, try both cases and post the output: `print_r(get_included_files());`

Comment: @strkol i think i found the culprit. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

The best way in general is to define the root directory on the site that is directly called by the user. So all index sites, that are supposed to by directly addressed by the user, but not in other .php files, that are included or classes and so on.

```
index.php:
$rootdir = '../';

require_once($rootdir.'dir/other.php);
```

Comment: Also useful is the [`__DIR__`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) constant.